# How to have an eventmachine server just write data?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I need to implement a server which only writes data, doesn't receive it.  All of the eventmachine server examples I've found always have the server receive data first, and then respond with data.  I need it to just start writing data to a client after a client connects.

I tried just putting a loop in post_init, but that doesn't seem to work... the client connects, the server writes, but the client never seems to receive anything.  Suggestions?

The test server:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'time'

module TestServer
  def post_init
    puts "-- client connected, sending data --"
    while true do
      send_data "Hello from TestServer\n"
      puts "sent #{Time.now.iso8601}"
    end
  end
end

EventMachine::run {
  EventMachine::start_server "127.0.0.1", 4001, TestServer
  puts 'running test server on 4001'
}
```

The test client:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

module Forwarder
  def post_init
    puts "-- connected to server --"
  end

  def receive_data data
    # none of the following is ever output
    puts "in receive_data"
    puts data
  end
end

EventMachine::run {
  EventMachine::connect '127.0.0.1', 4001, Forwarder
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tmm1 on #eventmachine, got this figured out.  Client is the same.  Server code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'time'

module TestServer
  def post_init
    puts "-- client connected --"
    @timer = EM::PeriodicTimer.new(0.1) {
      send_data "Hello from TestServer at #{Time.now.iso8601}\n"
    }
  end

end

EventMachine::run {
  EventMachine::start_server "127.0.0.1", 4001, TestServer
  puts 'running test server on 4001'
}
```